# Why are these nested options in a POSIX shell script being word-split?

Tags: shell-script, quoting

I have a script `count_args` that counts arguments:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $#
```

If I call it with these options, it tells me it gets two arguments:

```
$ ./count_args --options '1 2'
2
```

But if I construct the arguments in a script `test_args` like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
ARGS="--options '1 2'"
./count_args ${ARGS}
```

...I get the result:

```
$ ./test_args 
3
```

Why is the `'1 2'` being split in the script? How can I avoid this in a POSIX compliant way, *from the calling script*? Is it possible to still store arguments in variables somehow so that I can separate them in more complex scripts (eg. having `ARGS_1` and `ARGS_2`)?

Note that my `/bin/sh` is `dash`.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first case, the arguments passed to `count_args` were interpreted by the shell, the shell saw two words `--options` and `1 2` then passed them to `count_args`.

With second case, Inside double quotes, all characters except `$` and `\` are treated as literal. It's too late for the shell to interpret the single quotes, the shell saw the content of `$ARGS` variable as a long string `--options '1 2'`, all characters as literal and have no special meaning to the shell.

Using `${ARGS}` without double quotes made it subjected to fields splitting and filename expansion. With default value of `IFS`, you got three separated words: `--options`, `'1` and `2'`.

The best way to archive this is using `"$@"`:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -- --options '1 2'

./count_args "$@"
```

Comment: So I've updated my question to be a little more specific: is there a way to do this using variables to separate various options? Otherwise I could just write `./count_args --options '1 2'` right there in the script.

Comment: I don't want to bait and switch though, so you get the tick because you answered the question I *actually* asked, as opposed to the one in my head.

Comment: @detly [How do I store a command in a variable?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters/131767#131767)